# C# Get Crypto enum information from Request

Tags: c#, cryptography

I want to log TLS and crypto information about requests that come into my application. I can get this information  from

```
Request.ServerVariables["CRYPT_PROTOCOL"]
Request.ServerVariables["CRYPT_CIPHER_ALG_ID"]
Request.ServerVariables["CRYPT_KEYEXCHANGE_ALG_ID"]
Request.ServerVariables["CRYPT_HASH_ALG_ID"]
```

These will return id that corresponds to names defined https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/alg-id?redirectedfrom=MSDN and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/schannel/ns-schannel-secpkgcontext_connectioninfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN

So if I want to log that connection is made over need to get the key, lookup the string value and log it. In short, I need an enum that contains this data (and ideally is maintained by Microsoft as new methods get added) Does something like this exists in C# somewhere or do I need to hard code this list myself?

Comment: There's [TlsCipherSuite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.tlsciphersuite)

Comment: That is the sort information I want, but how to I convert the data from server variable to what's in the TlsCipherSuite?